# Replacing unknown items as mean of their similar in R

Tags: r

Take a look at this table:

```
  Industry City Week  Year  Budget
1 Hotel.    1    34   2005   10
2 Trans.    1    34   2005   10
3 Hotel.    1    34   2006   20
4 Trans.    2    35   2005   10
5 Hotel.    1    34   2007   NA
6 Trans.    3    34   2005   10
7 Hotel.    3    35   2005   10
8 Trans.    3    36   2005   10
```

I would like to replace all NAs with mean value of Budget of exact Industry, City and Week (ignoring the year).

So NA in this case will be 15 (mean of 1 and 3).

Comment: why isn't the mean of that NA 13.3333? since Hotel has 3 values that sum to 40

Comment: Different City for item 7

Answer (score 2):

Simple, only for your example (with one NA)

```
ds<-read.table(textConnection('1 Hotel.    1    34   2005   10
    2 Trans.    1    34   2005   10
    3 Hotel.    1    34   2006   20
    4 Trans.    2    35   2005   10
    5 Hotel.    1    34   2007   NA
    6 Trans.    3    34   2005   10
    7 Hotel.    3    35   2005   10
    8 Trans.    3    36   2005   10'))

colnames(ds)<-c('lp','Industry','City','Week','Year','Budget')

ds$Budget[is.na(ds$Budget)]<-15
```

But it can be extended if your data set consists of more observations

```
means<-aggregate(Budget~Industry+City+Week,data=ds,mean)
names(means)[ncol(means)]<-'BudgetMean'
ds.merged<-merge(x=ds,y=means,all.x=T)
ds.merged<-transform(ds.merged,
                     BudgetImp=ifelse(is.na(Budget),BudgetMean,Budget))
```

**edit**. 
The same thing with `plyr` package

```
library(plyr)
ds<-ddply(ds,.(Industry,City,Week),mutate,
          BudgetMean=mean(Budget,na.rm=T),
          Budget=ifelse(is.na(Budget),BudgetMean,Budget))
```

or even

```
ds<-ddply(ds,.(Industry,City,Week),mutate,
          Budget=ifelse(is.na(Budget),mean(Budget,na.rm=T),Budget))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `data.table` solution.

```
DF <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text='  Industry City Week  Year  Budget
Hotel.    1    34   2005   10
Trans.    1    34   2005   10
Hotel.    1    34   2006   20
Trans.    2    35   2005   10
Hotel.    1    34   2007   NA
Trans.    3    34   2005   10
Hotel.    3    35   2005   10
Trans.    3    34   2005   NA ', colClasses = c("character", rep("double", 4)))
```

Note that I changed last row a bit to further illustrate the example.

```
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(DF)
DT[, Budget := ifelse(is.na(Budget), mean(Budget, na.rm=TRUE), Budget), by = list(Industry, City, Week)]

DT
##    Industry City Week Year Budget
## 1:   Hotel.    1   34 2005     10
## 2:   Trans.    1   34 2005     10
## 3:   Hotel.    1   34 2006     20
## 4:   Trans.    2   35 2005     10
## 5:   Hotel.    1   34 2007     15
## 6:   Trans.    3   34 2005     10
## 7:   Hotel.    3   35 2005     10
## 8:   Trans.    3   36 2005     10
```